# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in ..\mortgage.php on line 2

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, sql

добрый день, помогите решить ошибку, указанную выше.

денвер установил только что, создал базу данных together посредством phpmyadmin, в ней табличку comments
создал пользователя makc с паролем 12345 и всеми правами доступа, привязал пользователя к базе данных
файл Z:\home\together.home\www\mortgage.php выглядит так:

```
<?
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','makc','12345'); 
mysql_select_db ("together", $db);
```

?>

при попытке соединиться получаю вышеуказанную ошибку, в правильности набора логина и пароля уверен, пробовал слещующий код:

```
<?
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
...
```

результат аналогичный

Comment: перезагрузите денвер

Answer (score 1):

привяжите root'a к этой же базе